# Cambiar el valor de una variable si cumple una condicion en R

Tags: r

Necesito cambiar el valor de una variable.

Una de ellas se llama `Village` y una de ellas se llama `site`. Una de los `Villages` que se llama `esperanza_paleta` tiene valor 5 en la variable `site` y quiero que ese 5 cambie por 4. Osea cuando el Village : `esperanza_paleta` tenga valor 5 en la variable site, cambielo por 4.

Intente, pero me sale como sigue:

```
> data <- data[ which(data$country=="peru"), ]#
> summary(data$site)
  2   3   4   5   6 
  0   0 833   2 171 
> data$site<- ifelse(data$village=="esperanza_paleta" & data$site==5,4,data$site)
> data$site<- as.factor(data$site)
> summary(data$site)
  3   4   5
833   2 171
```

Answer (score 1):

La solucion que te han facilitado es la correcta y deberías siempre ir a la solucion mas facil, te aporto otros enfoques solo con fin didactico que tambien consiguen lo mismo:

```
d <- c(2,2,12,10, 24,30,50,55,60)
e <- c("red", "white", "yellow")
car <- data.frame(d,e)
names(car) <- c("carro","Color") # variable names

# con plyr, muy fácil
library(plyr)
car$Color <- revalue(car$Color, c("red"=1))

# opcion2, cuando son factores
levels(car$Color)[levels(car$Color)=="red"] <- 1

# opcion 3, within
car <- within(car, levels(Color)[levels(Color) == "red"] <- 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Una cuarta opción utilizando el paquete [dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) (para los que prefieren el [tidyverse](http://www.tidyverse.org/packages/)):

```
library(dplyr)

car_antes <- tibble(carro = c(2, 2, 12, 10, 24, 30, 50, 55, 60),
                    color = rep(c("red", "white", "yellow"), 3)) # vectores de mismo largo

car_despues <- car_antes %>% 
                 mutate(carro = ifelse(color == "red", 1, carro))
```

Lo cual te daría para `car_antes`:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  carro  color
  <dbl>  <chr>
1     2    red
2     2  white
3    12 yellow
4    10    red
5    24  white
6    30 yellow
7    50    red
8    55  white
9    60 yellow
```

Y para `car_despues`:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  carro  color
  <dbl>  <chr>
1     1    red
2     2  white
3    12 yellow
4     1    red
5    24  white
6    30 yellow
7     1    red
8    55  white
9    60 yellow
```

Si necesitas modificar varias veces la variable `color` según condiciones diferentes, puede que la función `case_when()` (también de `dplyr`) te sea más útil.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te estoy interpretando adecuadamente, pero entiendo que en tu ejemplo quieres modificar el valor de la columna/variable `carro` por `1` si `color` es `red`. La forma más sencilla, creo que es la siguiente:

```
d <- c(2,2,12,10, 24,30,50,55,60)
e <- c("red", "white", "yellow")
car <- data.frame(d,e)
names(car) <- c("carro","Color") # variable names

car
car$carro[car$Color == "red"] <- 1
car
```

El antes:

```
  carro  Color
1     2    red
2     2  white
3    12 yellow
4    10    red
5    24  white
6    30 yellow
7    50    red
8    55  white
9    60 yellow
```

El después:

```
  carro  Color
1     1    red
2     2  white
3    12 yellow
4     1    red
5    24  white
6    30 yellow
7     1    red
8    55  white
9    60 yellow
```

Comment: Si gracias , creo q es la manera correcta!!! no se por q  aveces uno se compleja demasiado las cosas!! muchas gracias nuevamente